# Load image from URL and upload to media library in Strapi

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, strapi

I'm building a CSV importer for my Strapi application and one of its task is to read an image URL from a cell and download it from the URL and save it to media library.

The code looks like this:

```
const request = require('request').defaults({ encoding: null });

request.get(src, function (err, res, body) {
    const fileName = src.split('/').pop();

    strapi.plugins.upload.services.upload.upload({
        files: {
            path: body,
            name: fileName,
            type: res.headers['content-type'],
            size: Number(res.headers['content-length']),
        },
        data: {
            ref: 'products',
            refId: data.itemID,
            field: 'images'
        }
    });
});
```

The download works and I get a Buffer in the `body` variable of the `request.get` callback. But passing this to `strapi.plugins.upload.services.upload.upload` give me the following error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The argument 'path' must be a string or Uint8Array without null bytes. Received <Buffer ff d8 ff e1 10 c1 45 78 69 66 00 00 49 49 2a 00 08 00 00 00 0f 00 00 01 03 00 01 00 00 00 6c 05 00 00 01 01 03 00 01 00 ...
```

I already tried to replace `path: body,` with `path: new Uint8Array(body),` but without no luck.

Any idea what I do wrong here?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's pretty clear that the function expects a file pathname, not a buffer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had this exact same requirement in one of my projects where I had to fetch a file from an `URL` and then upload it to media library. I've approached the problem by first fetching the stream of bytes from the `URL` and then saving it to a file in a `tmp` folder. Once the file is fully downloaded, I've simply used the inbuilt `upload` method of `strapi` to upload the file to the media library.

###### Libraries you need to install

`$ npm install mime-types`
`$ npm install axios`
`$ npm install lodash`

###### Implementation

```js
// my-project/helpers/uploader.js

const _ = require('lodash');
const axios = require('axios').default;
const fs = require('fs');
const stream = require('stream');
const path = require('path');
const promisify = require('util').promisify;
const mime = require('mime-types');

module.exports = {
  getFileDetails(filePath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.stat(filePath, (err, stats) => {
        if (err) reject(err.message);
        resolve(stats);
      });
    });
  },

  deleteFile(filePath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.unlink(filePath, (err) => {
        if (err) reject(err.message);
        resolve('deleted');
      });
    });
  },

  async uploadToLibrary(imageByteStreamURL) {
    const filePath = './tmp/myImage.jpeg';
    const { data } = await axios.get(imageByteStreamURL, {
      responseType: 'stream',
    });

    const file = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
    const finished = promisify(stream.finished);
    data.pipe(file);
    await finished(file);
    const image = await this.upload(filePath, 'uploads');
    return image;
  },

  async upload(filePath, saveAs) {
    const stats = await this.getFileDetails(filePath);
    const fileName = path.parse(filePath).base;

    const res = await strapi.plugins.upload.services.upload.upload({
      data: { path: saveAs },
      files: {
        path: filePath,
        name: fileName,
        type: mime.lookup(filePath),
        size: stats.size,
      },
    });

    await this.deleteFile(filePath);
    return _.first(res);
  },
};
```

Then in you're actual service/controller you can simply invoke the method from your helper like so:

```js
const uploader = require('../../../helpers/uploader');
const img = await uploader.uploadToLibrary('http://www.example.com/demo-image.jpg');
console.log(img);
```

###### References:

- [Mime-Types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime-types)
- [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)
- [Lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash)

Comment: Thanks Salvino! Your answer is pure gold! I just had to do a few tweaks and it worked!

Comment: Glad to help. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks Salvino. There should be such a built-in service in strapi

Comment: Yep, totally agree on that.

Comment: Thank you very much Salvino!! Helped me a lot!!!

Comment: This is great! Thank you <3

When returning `return res[0]` instead `return _.first(res);`  you don't need `lodash` as dependency.

When developing a plugin you can use `const filePath = \`${process.env.PWD}/.tmp/myImage.jpeg\`;` as file path :)