# Strapi: Auto-populate the field values based on the values in other fields in a content type

Tags: npm, content-management-system, strapi

**Strapi Version: v4
Operating System: macOS
Database: MySQL
Node Version: 16.15
NPM Version: 5.8.8**

I am trying to populate a field based on the value in other fields.
Example: I have a content type with fields city = Mumbai and country = India, now I need a third field called market which should have the value Mumbai - India (i.e. value of city field + “-” + value of country field).

I'm relatively newer to strapi and still exploring the tool, Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is pretty simple to achieve with the help of Strapi's [Model Lifecyle Hooks](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/models.html#lifecycle-hooks).

**Step 1:**

Firstly, add the `city`, `county` & `market` fields to your collection type via the `Content-Type builder`.

**Step 2:** 

Now, you need to make the field `read-only` to make sure that nobody gets to manually populate the field via the admin UI. You can do this by visiting any entry from your collection and then clicking on the `Configure the view` option from the right hand pane.

[image]

**Step 3:** 

Next, click on the edit icon against the `market` field. You will be presented with a popup similar to the below screenshot. Make the field as Editable `false` and click on `finish`. Once this is done, make sure you click on the `Save` button shown in the top right hand side corner of the page to permanently save your changes.

[image]

**Step 4:** 

Next, override the `beforeCreate` & `beforeUpdate` lifecycle hooks of the model to auto-populate the market values while entries are created/updated. To do this, you'll have to create a lifecycles.js file in the following folder: `./api/[api-name]/content-types/[content-type-name]/`

Let's say your collection name is `Student`.

```js
// src/api/student/content-types/student/lifecycles.js

module.exports = {
    beforeCreate(event) {
    if (event.params.data.city && event.params.data.country) {
      const { city = "", country = "" } = event.params.data;
      event.params.data.market = city + " - " + country;
    }
  },

  beforeUpdate(event) {
    if (event.params.data.city && event.params.data.country) {
      const { city = "", country = "" } = event.params.data;
      event.params.data.market = city + " - " + country;
    }
  },
};
```

**Step 5:** 

That's it! Restart your strapi server and try creating or updating new entries in your collection. It should automatically populate the `market` value based on the `city` & `country` values.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer Salvino, it really helped me make some progress. Though the solution is fine until I publish my content, it populates the field with a value "undefined-undefined" once I hit the publish button. Do you know why it might be happening?

Comment: @grvkgp I've updated my answer. So the issue is that when you publish an entry, the `beforeUpdate` event is triggered with just the `publishedAt` & `updatedAt` times. You can easily solve this by surrounding your code with an `if` condition that checks for valid values before updating. Also, please accept this answer so that it may help others in future.

Comment: also, I was taking a look at your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70674721/load-image-from-url-and-upload-to-media-library-in-strapi  
Can you please help me understand it a little to achieve the same using python?

Comment: Sorry brother, I don't posses prior knowledge of python. :-(