# Strapi: Populate a JSON field with information from the content-type itself

Tags: api, vue.js, nuxt.js, strapi

I have a product content-type that I've added a JSON content-field to.

On create/update of a product, it should populate the JSON field with the created id of that product, name which lives on the product and price which also lives on the product along with anything I should choose in future - the JSON string needs to be formatted like so:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "price": 79.99,
  "url": "https://strapi-endpoint.com/api/product/1"
}
```

I read this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72318872/strapi-auto-populate-the-field-values-based-on-the-values-in-other-fields-in-a) and managed to get some JSON into the field on the hooks, but I'm just a little bit stuck on how to get the ID to go in from the DB on all the hooks? i.e. afterCreate or afterUpdate, how to get DB values in at this stage?

For reference the json field I want to populate is called "snipcartCrawl":

[image: product content-type]

My secondary question to tag along would be how to target this field specifically using strapi API and bypass the `data` and `attribute` nesting so that I can access the json field value I am creating above via a specific API call.