# How to upload an image to a Strapi controller?

Tags: controller, upload, strapi

I have a controller that receives an api response. Among other things, I receive online image URLs.
So from these urls I am trying to save the image in Strapi and receive the corresponding ID to save the rest.
But I don't have the right method.

For that I made a function in a service :

```
export async function uploadImageByUrl(imageUrl) {
    const imageBuffer = await axios(imageUrl).then((response) => response.data);
    const formData = new FormData();
    const filename = imageUrl.split('/').pop();
    formData.append('files', imageBuffer, filename);
...
}
```

But I can't save the file using the plugin or the service.
What is the right method?

Thanks for any advice or help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70674721/load-image-from-url-and-upload-to-media-library-in-strapi?r=Saves_AllUserSaves